# Outlook Add-in not loaded via Exchange 2013

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, add-in

We have developed an Outlook Add-in which was deployed on its web server. The Add-in can be sideloaded for Office 365 and Outlook.com accounts and no issue at all. But for Exchange accounts, we found 3 issues by following two documents below. Are there any special settings we missed for Exchange server or email accounts?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-requirements Outlook add-in requirements
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/testing-and-tips Deploy and install Outlook add-ins for testing

1. Sideload can be done via online email, but cannot via Outlook client (no Store icon on ribbon). Is it designed like this?
2. After Add-in manifest file uploaded, Add-in not shown with email in Outlook client, just shown with online email as a “Contextual Outlook add-ins”, but supposed to be a “Add-in commands”.
3. If click the Add-in, a blank page expanded as screenshot below.
   [screenshot after clicked on the Add-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuUhR.jpg)

Comment: We also deployed and tried the sample Add-in "Gist" https://github.com/jasonjoh/git-the-gist. After installed, this Add-in still shown as a "Contextual Outlook Add-ins", not as a side panel.

Answer (score 0):

All issues are related to certificates used for Exchange 2013. We just found certificates issue and resolved it, now everything is good.

Comment: After Exchange 2013 server was set up, one certificate was assigned but this certificate is only valid for the mail domain "mail.xyz.com", not for the auto discover domain "autodiscover.xyz.com". After we assigned another certificate which is valid for above both domains, then everything is good now.